# PHP Session variable does not set in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, safari, session-variables

I have a NEW problem when using PHP session variables. The problem is, they seem to all work in Chrome and FireFox, but will NOT work in Safari on my iPhone (note: currently I am unable to access the local page to test it with Internet Explorer, but that's outside the scope of this issue I would think).

This is a particular problem when I log in a user on a website I'm working on. Here is the code:

index.php

```
<?php session_start();
include ("dbconfig.php");
 ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "site.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="index.html?img=favicon" type="image/ico" />
    <script>

            function validatingForm(){
                var x;
                var y;
                var e;
                var p;

                x = document.getElementById('nameCheck').value;
                y = document.getElementById('password').value;
                e = document.getElementById('errorMsg');
                p = document.getElementById('errorPass');

                if(x !="" && y !=""){
                    return true;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == ""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!=""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(y =="" && x!=""){
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        return false;
                        }

            }
        function validatingSignUpForm(){
                var x;
                var y;
                var e;
                var p;

                x = document.getElementById('newonameCheck').value;
                y = document.getElementById('newopassword').value;
                e = document.getElementById('newoerrorMsg');
                p = document.getElementById('newoerrorPass');

                if(x !="" && y !=""){
                    return true;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == ""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!=""){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(y =="" && x!=""){
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        return false;
                        }

            }
        function addValidate(){
                var x;
                var y;
                var z;
                var e;
                var p;
                var r;

                x = document.getElementById('nameCheck').value;
                y = document.getElementById('password').value;
                z = document.getElementById('role').value;
                e = document.getElementById('errorMsg');
                p = document.getElementById('errorPass');
                r = document.getElementById('errorRole');

                if(x !="" && y !="" && z !="empty"){
                    return true;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == "" & z == "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x !="" && y == "" & z == "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!="" && z == "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == "" && z != "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!="" && z != "empty"){
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(y =="" && x!="" && z != "empty"){
                        p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        e.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        r.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Role:</font>';
                        return false;
                        }

            }
        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
                <?php

                if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
                        /* user is logged in */
                        echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Hi, ". $_SESSION['user'] . "! Welcome to the site!</p>";
                else
                        /* user is NOT logged in*/
                        echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Please Login:</p>
                                        <form action='welcome.php' method='post'>
                                            <center><b id = 'errorMsg'>Name:</b>
                                            <input type='text' id='nameCheck' name = 'username' /></center>
                                            <br />
                                            <center><b id='errorPass'>Password:</b> <input type='password' id ='password' name = 'password'/></center>
                                            <br /><br />
                                            <center><input type='submit' value='Log In' onClick='return validatingForm()'/></center>
                                        </form>

                              <p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> OR Sign Up:</p>
                                        <form action='sign_up.php' method='post'>
                                            <center><b id = 'newoerrorMsg'>Name:</b>
                                            <input type='text' id='newonameCheck' name = 'addusername' /></center>
                                            <br />
                                            <center><b id='newoerrorPass'>Password:</b> <input type='password' id ='newopassword' name = 'addpassword'/></center>
                                            <br /><br />
                                            <center><input type='submit' value='Sign Up' onClick='return validatingSignUpForm()'/></center>
                                        </form>
                                        ";
                ?>
            <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'admin') {

                    /*query user db */
                    $user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users");

                    /* Assume there is a recordset and create the table */
                    echo "<center>
                            <h1> User List:</h1>
                            <table border='1'>
                            <tr>
                            <td><b>User ID</b></td>
                            <td><b>Username</b></td>
                            <td><b>Password</b></td>
                            <td><b>Options</b></td>
                            </tr>";

                            /* loop through recordset - new row for each user */
                            while( $record = $user_rs->fetch_object() ){
                                echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>" . $record->id . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->username . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->password . "</td>
                                        <td><a href='remove_user.php?id=" . $record->id . "'>Delete</a></td>  
                                    </tr>";
                            }
                            /* Close the table */
                            echo "
                                </table>
                            </center>
                            <br />";
                            }
                else if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 'user') {

                    /*query user db */
                    $user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'");

                    /* Assume there is a recordset and create the table */
                    echo "<center>
                            <h1> Your Profile:</h1>
                            <table border='1'>
                            <tr>
                            <td><b>User ID</b></td>
                            <td><b>Username</b></td>
                            <td><b>Password</b></td>
                            </tr>";

                            /* take one row for user only */
                            $record = $user_rs->fetch_object();
                                echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>" . $record->id . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->username . "</td>
                                        <td>" . $record->password . "</td>
                                    </tr>";

                            /* Close the table */
                            echo "
                                </table>
                            </center>
                            <br />";
                            }
                #else {
                    #do nothing
                #   }
            ?>
            <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['role']=="admin")
                    echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Add User:</p>
                                <form action='add_user.php' method='post' onSubmit='return addValidate();' style = 'border: 2px grey solid; padding: 5px'>
                                    <b id='errorMsg'>Name:</b>
                                    <input type='text' id='nameCheck' name='addusername'/>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <b id='errorPass'>Password:</b> <input type='password' id='password' name='addpassword'/>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <b id='errorRole'>Role:</b> <select name='addrole' id='role' >
                                    <option value='empty'>Select Role</option>
                                    <option value='admin'>Admin</option>
                                    <option value='user'>Ordinary User</option></select>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <input type='submit' value='Add'/>
                                </form>";
                                ?>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
                echo "<center><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></center>";?>  

            <p class = "content"> This is a page that is a scrap work in progress. </p>


            <?php include("footer.php"); ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
include('dbconfig.php');?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Webpage</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "site.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="index.html?img=favicon" type="image/ico" />
<body>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<p class="welcome" id="greeting">
<?php

    $usercheck = $_POST["username"];
    $passcheck = $_POST["password"];
    $db_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $usercheck . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_con, $db_query);
    if(!$result) {
        die(mysqli_error($db_con));
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $record = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if (md5($passcheck) == $record['password']){
            echo "Welcome, " . $_POST["username"] . "! You are now logged in. <br/>";
            $_SESSION['user']= $_POST["username"];
            $_SESSION['pass']= $passcheck;
            $_SESSION['role']= $record['role'];
            }
        else
            echo "Sorry, wrong password. <br/>";
        }
    else
        echo "No such user exists... <br />";
?>
<a href="index.php">Click here</a> to return to the main page.
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your specific problem? The session variables don't seem to be set? You may want to check the username and password you're getting from the browser. The browser has no effect on how the PHP code runs, since it's all server-side, but it can effect the input the PHP script gets from the browser.

Comment: Browser shouldn't affect session variables (since they are server-generated). Check your `document.cookie` and see if the SESSION ID is the same

Comment: Yes, check cookies.  If PHP is set to use_only_cookies and Safari is set to reject cookies from the site, that'd be a good explanation of your issue.

Most browser debuggers know allow cookie inspection.  It should be a simple matter of checking cookies in FFox (Q or Firebug) or in the Chrome Debugger, and then in Safari's debugger.

Since you're debugging *mobile* Safari, you may need an iPhone debugging site like http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator-for-iphone-5.php

Comment: @Kkinsey I tried the simulator- what's weird is, the login totally works. However, it doesn't work when I try it from my ACTUAL iPhone 5s Safari browser...

Comment: @PhilipTsang I'm so sorry... I'm still relatively new to this... I just tried setting the inner HTML of a debug div to document.cookie. That doesn't seem to work?... is there a better way to check this value?

Comment: Never mind. @PhilipTsang just an update... I DID try printing document.cookie in an alert on all of the browsers I test. Interestingly enough, each browser returns a PHPSessionID string EXCEPT for the Safari Mobile browser, which is blank. Also, this ONLY appears to happen on the Safari Mobile browser- a friend told me it worked fine from Safari on his desktop computer

Comment: @Kkinsey for some reason it works just fine on desktop Safari, just not Mobile. I'm about to get feedback from a friend about Internet Explorer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I get a cookie string returned when I try to access from my Mobile browser LOCALLY on the same network as the server (using my IP address)... but when hitting from outside the network, empty string.

Comment: Another update: this appears to work entirely in Safari when I move cookie permissions in my iPhone's Safari settings from "Websites I Visit" to "Always." As soon as I move the permissions back to "Websites I Visit," NO COOKIES ARE STORED!